# Getting an AlertDialog to save its checkboxes state between calls

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, persistence

I have a DialogFragment (android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment) which I instantiate with:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
  LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();  
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, null);
  builder.setView(v);
  ...
}
```

I haven't setRetainInstance so by default it is false.

In that dialog I have a few checkbox and I would like the state of them to be remembered between calls to this dialog. I have put no buttons on the dialog and I rely on the user to click outside the dialog to close it.

When the screen orientation changes everything works fine; the dialog is recreated in the other orientation and the selection of the user is preserved. This seems to happen automagically because the method onSaveInstanceState is called.

I would like to benefit of the same magic when my dialog is closed and I notice that onSaveInstanceState is not called when the user clicks outside the dialog.

My instinct is to force a call to onSaveInstanceState from within onDismiss (which does get called when the dialog is closed). But onSaveInstanceState requires a Bundle as an argument and I can't find something sensible to pass to it. I have tried calling getArguments() but this returns null.

So is there an argument I could pass to onSaveInstanceState() which would buy me the same magic that I get on orientation change?
I am also open to other simple ways to preserve the state of my dialog between calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know abt `OnSaveInstanceState` but u can create `Boolean` variables for each checkboxes and in `OnCheckedChangeListener` for each checkbox you can save the state of checkbox in those boolean variables.

OR

U can also use `SharedPreferences` to store states of ur checkboxes

and for accessing checkboxes that r inside ur alert dialog u have to use

```
CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id._cbox);
                           ^^^^^
```

hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I am hoping to understand better the lifecycle of fragments through this question. However how and when would you restore the state of your checkboxes with your solution?

Comment: It does indeed seems like the only way is to manually save all my checkboxes state in a boolean[] variable. Furthermore, this has to be a **static** variable of my Dialog subclass otherwise the state of these variables gets wiped with the replacement of one object by the next. 
This seems awfully awkward for such a simple ask. I was somehow hoping that the bits that work so well on screen reorientation change could be taken advantage here too. But when the dialog is dismissed and later invoked, the bundle has been reset so it doesn't seem to be possible.